# Оператор throws и исключения

Tags: java

Всем привет, друзья! Хотелось бы спросить:
checked исключения, как я понял обязательно должны содержать оператор throws в сигнатуре метода или обрабатываться в конструкции try, catch?
Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да. Это во всех книжках по началам Java написано.

Comment: Не очень понятно, новичок

Comment: Все просто, обязательное исключение. Или ловите или бросаете следующему. Проигнорировать нельзя.

Answer (score 4):

Если написать что-то которое относится допустим к `checked` исключениям: тот же `FileNotFoundException`, то Idea вас попросит либо обернуть это в try, catch конструкцию либо вам нужно будет добавить в сигнатуру метода оператор `throws` и класс (`FileNotFoundException`) это для `checked`.
А для unchecked вы можете написать:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;
int c = a/b;
System.out.print(c)
```

`//выведет Arithmetic exception`, но так как `Arithmetic exception` это класс `unchecked`, Idea вас не будет просить обернуть это в конструкцию `try, catch` либо добавить оператор throws в сигнатуру метода потому что это `UNCHECKED` исключения

Answer (score 2):

Да, это все написано в спецификации, в [главе 11 «Исключения»](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html).

Виды исключений определены в [§11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)

> **11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions**
>   ...
>
> - Exception is the superclass of all the exceptions from which ordinary programs may wish to recover.
>     The class RuntimeException is a direct subclass of Exception. RuntimeException is the superclass of all the exceptions which may be thrown for many reasons during expression evaluation, but from which recovery may still be possible.
>     RuntimeException and all its subclasses are, collectively, the run-time exception classes.
> - Error is the superclass of all the exceptions from which ordinary programs are not ordinarily expected to recover.
>     Error and all its subclasses are, collectively, the error classes.
>
> The *unchecked exception* classes are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>   The *checked exception* classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes.
>
> **11.1.1. Виды исключений**
>   ...
>
> - Exception является суперклассом для всех исключений, от которых программы могут пожелать восстановиться.
>     Класс RuntimeException является непосредственным наследником Exception. RuntimeException представляет собой суперкласс всех исключений, которые могут быть сгенерированы по разным причинам в процессе определения выражения, но восстановление после которых еще возможно.
>     RuntimeException и его подклассы коллективно представляют собой классы исключений времени выполнения.
> - Error является суперклассом всех исключений, при которых восстановление обычных программ невозможно.
>     Error и его подклассы коллективно представляют собой классы ошибок.
>
> Классами *непроверяемых исключений* являются классы исключений времени выполнения и ошибок.
>   Классами *проверяемых исключений* являются все классы исключений, кроме проверяемых.

Проверяемое исключение должно быть либо поймано, либо определено в throws метода или конструктора, в противном случае возникает ошибка компиляции. При этом в throws может быть определено

Это описано в [§11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3)

> **11.2.3. Exception Checking**
>   It is a compile-time error if a method or constructor body *can throw* some exception class E when E is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of some class declared in the throws clause of the method or constructor.
>
> **11.2.3. Проверка исключений**
>   Если тело метода или конструктора *может генерировать* некоторый класс исключений E, где E — класс проверяемого исключения и E не является подклассом некоторого класса, объявленного в конструкции throws метода или конструктора, то генерируется ошибка компиляции.

Какие блоки и в каких случаях могут генерировать те или иные исключения описано в §11.2.1 и §11.2.2. Для лучшего понимания, советую прочитать всю 11-ю главу, она достаточно коротка, содержит примеры и полно описывает работу с исключениями в Java.